# Change day/month language in DialogFlow bot

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot

I'm creating an assistant for an italian restaurant using DialogFlow.

I've set the language to spanish, and everything seems to go fine, but when i show the final date of the reservation it is shown in english (Friday and May in attached picture's case).

Is it possible to change it?
[image]

This is the code that generates the above particular response to a table booking process:

```
function createBooking(agent) {
    let guests = agent.parameters.comensales;
    let time = new Date(agent.parameters.time);
    let date = new Date(agent.parameters.date);
    let bookingDate = new Date(date);
    var numeroReserva = Math.random().toString(16).slice(2, 8).toUpperCase();
    bookingDate.setHours(time.getHours());
    bookingDate.setMinutes(time.getMinutes());
    let now = new Date();

    if (guests < 1){
        agent.add('You need to reserve a table for at least one person. Please try again!');
    } else if (bookingDate < now){
        agent.add(`No puedes reservar una fecha pasada. Por favor, inténtalo de nuevo!`);
    } else if (bookingDate.getFullYear() > now.getFullYear()) {
        agent.add(`No puedes hacer una reserva para ${bookingDate.getFullYear()} todavía. Por favor, elige una fecha en ${now.getFullYear()}.`);
    } else {
        let timezone = parseInt(agent.parameters.time.toString().slice(19,22));
        bookingDate.setHours(bookingDate.getHours() + timezone);
        agent.add(`Perfecto. He reservado una mesa para ${guests} el ${bookingDate.toString().slice(0,21)}`);
        agent.add(`Tu código de reserva es: ${numeroReserva}`);
        agent.add('Nos vemos pronto!');
        agent.add('Buon appetito!');
    }
  }
```

Comment: How are you populating the response?  Is it a webhook or some other mechanism?  If you could elaborate on how the response is being built I think that would help.

Comment: @Kolban You are right, i should've elaborated. Im using Fulfillment and using the js function i just attached in the question.

Answer (score 1):

The code running the fulfillment runs within Google's compute infrastructure which has a default locale/language of US English.  When a request arrives for fullfilment from Dialog flow, that request carries with it the language that we are to use to respond.  See the `languageCode` in the [Webhook Request JSON](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/fulfillment-how).  When we use the APIs in Node.js, it *looks like* this data is available in the `agent.locale` property.

Looking at the JavaScript [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) object, we seem to have a method on it called `toLocaleString()` which converts a date/time into a string but additionally supplies the language (locale) to be used to create the language specific content and format.  If we put all this together, we might find that the following code line may work:

```
agent.add(`Perfecto. He reservado una mesa para ${guests} el ${bookingDate.toLocalString(agent.locale).slice(0,21)}`);
```

This may take a few tests to get right.  I'd start by logging `agent.locale` as a test to ensure that it has the value we expect/hope.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and response. Im trying many combinations with the toLocaleString method but all it does is changing it to 'European' format (example, today is: 2019-5-8) but it doesn't convert the date to weekday/month. Tried this also: `bookingDate.toLocaleString('es','ES')` but same result

Comment: Can you post an example of what you have coded, what exactly you are seeing and what exactly you hope to see?    Read also this in detail ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString   it appears that there are many possible options.

Comment: My desired output would be the first output of the example you attached. In the image of the post you have the output i was originally getting, which was also desired, but just changing the weekday and month to spanish. `bookingDate.toLocaleDateString('es-ES',options).slice(0,21)` with this line (being options the same as in your example) im getting this: _Perfecto. He reservado una mesa para 5 el 2019 M05 9, Thu_

Comment: It is possible that we are stepping out of DialogFlow land and into JavaScript native.  Imagine DialogFlow were not involved and you wanted to format a date into a format of your choice ... can we do that?  It appears that packages such as https://momentjs.com/ look like they can assist.

Comment: That library looks really interesting, thank you. Does the DialogFlow editor allow library imports? The thing is, let's forget the format, let's say im all happy with the format on the original post image. The main issue would be to translate the weekday/month to spanish, thats what i cant figure out how to do.

Answer (score 1):

It's late but for those who face with this problem. You know you can do it like this:

```
let options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric', 
                hour12: false, hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric' };
var curr_date = new Date();
agent.add(`Sono le ` + curr_date.toLocaleString('it-IT', options));
```

Answer (score 1):

If someone likes to use moment.js

you can add library to your project from fulfillment inline editor.
Go to Fulfillment, click on "package.json"

add the following lines in dependencies

```
"moment": "^2.24.0",
"moment-timezone": "^0.5.31"
```

Then back to index.js and add the following line to import it

const moment = require('moment-timezone');

and then you can handle like this in your function

```
if(agent.locale === 'en'){
         moment.locale('en-US');
         agent.add(`Now is ` + moment().tz(your_time_zone).format('LLLL'));
       }
       else if(agent.locale === 'it-IT' || agent.locale === 'it'){
         moment.locale('it');
         agent.add(`Sono le ` + moment().tz(your_time_zone).format('LLLL'));
       }
```

The sample of response is " Sono le martedì 20 ottobre 2020 15:30"
or "Now is Tuesday, October 20, 2020 3:31 PM"